# Find substring of string w/o knowing the length of string

Tags: string, lua

I have a string x: `x = "{abc}{def}{ghi}"`
And I need to print the string between second `{` and second `}`, in this case `def`. How can I do this without knowing the length of the string? For example, the string x could also be `{abcde}{fghij}{klmno}"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where pattern matching is useful:

```
local x = "{abc}{def}{ghi}"
local result = x:match(".-{.-}.-{(.-)}")
print(result)
```

`.-` matches zero or more characters, non-greedy. The whole pattern `.-{.-}.-{(.-)}` captures what's between the second `{` and the second `}`.

Answer (score 2):

Try also `x:match(".-}{(.-)}")`, which is simpler.

Answer (score 2):

I would go about it in a different manner:

```
local i, x, result = 1, "{abc}{def}{ghi}"
for w in x:gmatch '{(.-)}' do
  if i == 2 then
    result = w
    break
  else
    i = i + 1
  end
end
print( result )
```

Comment: I think you want `'{(.-)}'` instead of `'{.-}'` because the OP does not want the braces.